# how to create multiple containers in boost shared memory?

Tags: boost, shared-memory

Constructing multiple objects in shared memory is possible as shown in this example:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

void construct_objects(managed_shared_memory &managed_shm)
{
  managed_shm.construct<int>("Integer")(99);
  managed_shm.construct<float>("Float")(3.14);
}

int main()
{
  shared_memory_object::remove("Boost");
  managed_shared_memory managed_shm{open_or_create, "Boost", 1024};
  auto atomic_construct = std::bind(construct_objects,
    std::ref(managed_shm));
  managed_shm.atomic_func(atomic_construct);
  std::cout << *managed_shm.find<int>("Integer").first << '\n';
  std::cout << *managed_shm.find<float>("Float").first << '\n';
}
```

But when I try to create two vectors or a vector and a list, I run into problems with the memory allocation. Is there a way to create multiple containers in a single shared memory in Boost?
I had a look at `managed_memory_impl.hpp`, but it wasn't of much help either.
This is my code (you have to link it with lib pthread and librt):

```
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_semaphore.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/list.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <cstdlib> //std::system
#include <cstddef>
#include <cassert>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<int, boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemAllocator; //Define an STL compatible allocator of ints that allocates from the managed_shared_memory. This allocator will allow placing containers in the segment 
typedef boost::interprocess::vector<int, ShmemAllocator> MyVector; //Alias a vector that uses the previous STL-like allocator so that allocates its values from the segment

typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<int, boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemListAllocator;
typedef boost::interprocess::list<int, ShmemListAllocator> MyList;    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      //Construct managed shared memory
      boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory segment(boost::interprocess::create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);

      //const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst(segment.get_segment_manager());
      MyVector *instance = segment.construct<MyVector>("MyType instance")(segment.get_segment_manager());
      MyVector *instance2 = segment.construct<MyVector>("MyType instance")(segment.get_segment_manager());
      MyList *instance3 = segment.construct<MyList>("MyList instance")(segment.get_segment_manager());
   return 0;
}//main
```

Comment: You should be more specific than "I run into problems with the memory allocation". We're having to guess now

Comment: Sorry, I meant that instance2 and instance3 are not getting created because getsegmentmanager gets the same segment manager of instance1 and this throws an error

Comment: That's simply false logic. Segment managers manage segments. They can (obviously) contain more than one object. (Why else would there be names)

Comment: Thats what even i thought. Please run the code and see. It crashes

Comment: I don't get why you seem to be so annoyed/impatient. Just look at my Boost Interprocess answers. I really don't need to run this. Anyhow, I've updated my answer with live, running, samples. If something still doesn't work, we should start looking at the environment involved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should either use unique names, or you can use the indexed ("array") style of construction.

See the documentation for the [Object construction function family](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_memory_segment_features.allocation_types):

```
//!Allocates and constructs an array of objects of type MyType (throwing version)
//!Each object receives the same parameters (par1, par2, ...)
MyType *ptr = managed_memory_segment.construct<MyType>("Name")[count](par1, par2...);
```

and

```
//!Tries to find a previously created object. If not present, allocates and
//!constructs an array of objects of type MyType (throwing version). Each object
//!receives the same parameters (par1, par2, ...)
MyType *ptr = managed_memory_segment.find_or_construct<MyType>("Name")[count](par1, par2...);
```

and

```
//!Allocates and constructs an array of objects of type MyType (throwing version)
//!Each object receives parameters returned with the expression (*it1++, *it2++,... )
MyType *ptr = managed_memory_segment.construct_it<MyType>("Name")[count](it1, it2...);
```

and possibly some more. Look for `[count]`.

(I recommend using unique names for simplicity)

### Update

To the comments, here's what I meant with "unique name". I've tested it, and itworks fine:

**<kbd>[Live<sup>1</sup> On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9fdb10da3f2b3d9)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/list.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <cassert>

typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<int, boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>
    ShmemAllocator; // Define an STL compatible allocator of ints that allocates from the managed_shared_memory. This allocator
                    // will allow placing containers in the segment
typedef boost::interprocess::vector<int, ShmemAllocator> MyVector; // Alias a vector that uses the previous STL-like allocator so
                                                                   // that allocates its values from the segment

typedef boost::interprocess::allocator<int, boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> ShmemListAllocator;
typedef boost::interprocess::list<int, ShmemListAllocator> MyList;

int main()
{
    // Construct managed shared memory
    std::remove("/dev/shm/MySharedMemory");
    boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory segment(boost::interprocess::create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);

    // const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst(segment.get_segment_manager());
    MyVector *instance  = segment.construct<MyVector>("MyType instance 1")(segment.get_segment_manager());
    MyVector *instance2 = segment.construct<MyVector>("MyType instance 2")(segment.get_segment_manager());
    MyList   *instance3 = segment.construct<MyList>  ("MyList instance")(segment.get_segment_manager());

    assert(instance);
    assert(instance2);
    assert(instance3);

    assert(!std::equal_to<void*>()(instance,  instance2));
    assert(!std::equal_to<void*>()(instance,  instance3));
    assert(!std::equal_to<void*>()(instance2, instance3));
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course, SHM is not supported on Coliru. However, identical sample using mapped file: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f805ed81a7e570a0)**

Comment: Thanks sehe, but the reason i posted was because i wanted to create containers like how i did in my code and although i had been through the boost documentation, i could not understand how those parameters could be replaced by the return value of getsegmentmanager

Comment: What specifically is different in your perception?

Comment: I've updated my answer with live, running, samples that demonstrate what I mean. I hope you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Ah so it was the naming that caused the error! Thank you very much sehe :-) It works now.

Comment: @Nav I guess that was the first line of my answer all along :) Glad it works now